# Successfully reading data from printer with ReadPrinter Winspool.drv

Tags: c#, printing

I'm having some problems when sending raw command to a FGL-enabled Practical Automation ITX3002 ticket printer. I've been searching the whole day and I wasn't able to find a working example of using the ReadPrinter method from the winspool.drv Windows library.

Most code samples I've found, were related to network printers. This is a simple printer connected via usb. I need to retrieve some commands which response structure I already know (composite structure, well documented by the vendor).

I am able to send FGL commands to print normal and diagnostic ticket successfully. My problem, is reading back the data from the printer. I've read the Microsoft documentation found in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162895(v=vs.85).aspx and several other places. The doc doesn't explain how to SEND the data which this method is reading.

So, I really don't know if I have to call WritePrinter with the commands I need, close the handle, then call ReadPrinter to retrieve the data, or if I have to do everything in a single printer handle management (I mean, open, work and close a printer handle).

The vendor has been very patient with me, but the responses don't give me any help on how to get this.

This is my code:

```
    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "ReadPrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern Boolean ReadPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, StringBuilder data, Int32 cbBuf, out Int32 pNoBytesRead);


    public static Boolean ReadBytesFromPrinter(String szPrinterName, out String data)
    {
        Int32 dwError = 0, dwWritten = 0;
        IntPtr hPrinter = new IntPtr(0);
        DOCINFOA di = new DOCINFOA();
        Boolean bSuccess = false; // Assume failure unless you specifically succeed.
        data = null;

        di.pDocName = "SendBytesToPrinter";
        di.pDataType = "RAW";


        // Open the printer.
        if (OpenPrinter(szPrinterName.Normalize(), out hPrinter, IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            // Start a document.
            if (StartDocPrinter(hPrinter, 1, di))
            {
                // Start a page.
                if (StartPagePrinter(hPrinter))
                {
                    Int32 maxRead = 256;
                    StringBuilder sbData = new StringBuilder(maxRead);

                    //Read Data                
                    bSuccess = ReadPrinter(hPrinter, sbData, maxRead, out dwWritten);
                    data = sbData.ToString();

                    EndPagePrinter(hPrinter);                        

                    EndDocPrinter(hPrinter);

                    ClosePrinter(hPrinter);
                }

            }
        }
        // If you did not succeed, GetLastError may give more information
        // about why not.
        if (bSuccess == false)
        {
            dwError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            data = null;
        }

        return bSuccess;
    }
```

ReadPrinter always return "false", and the call to GetLastWin32Error is always zero. In other words, there is an error, no clues about what, and no data is read back.

I'm sending the commands as explained in http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322091 and it's successfully working as expected, with print commands and diagnostic ticket printing.

Does anyone knows the right handshaking between the code and the printer? How it's supposed to write the commands, and how to read response back? For me, it's no sense having to create a print job, a print document, and a print page to retrieve the data (I've already tryed that, BTW).  Am I missing something? Am I making something wrong?

Comment: Well, the snippet makes no sense at all.  You need OpenPrinter, then WritePrinter to send a command that's supposed to return data, then ReadPrinter to actually read it.  You ought to ask the vendor for a program example in any language.  If they can't give you one then write this off as practical, if the vendor cannot do it with his own product then you have no hope.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Hans. If I OpenPrinter, then WritePrinter, then Read, an error will be thrown (vshost32.exe stop working). If I call "StartDocPrinter", before WritePrinter, no error is thrown but the Read call does not return data. I don't think this is a particular issue with our vendor, ReadByte examples are very scarce and they should work fine for any bidirectional printer. The vendor is successfully reading from printer, but do not expose all commands to the api he provided. And I wasn't able to reverse engineering it to replicate the calls...

Comment: Clearly, instead of a code snippet that can never work, you should post the code that the vendor gave you that *does* work.  Only way to give somebody here a shot at helping you.

Comment: Code that vendor gave do not allow to send an arbitrary command to printer and read data back. The set of available commands exposed by vendor is smaller than the set of valid commands. I insist, this is simple bidirectional communication with a printer, the winspool.drv exposes a method to read back but there is no working example about that. I am wondering if someone was able to read anything from the printer with a command, how the handshaking should it be and how the calls has to be made. The output will be vendor-dependant, but the whole process via the winspool.drv will not.

Comment: I had the same problem with a ZPL printer, to avoid this, I had to use a serial communication between printer and computer. Many manufacturers provide virtualcom-Usb driver for these purposes. With this you will use a serial bidirectional communication between printer and computer.

Comment: I think that you should disable the caching in the spooler, so that the spooler writes the data directly to the printer. (Obviously, ReadPrinter cannot work if the command has not been sent to the printer yet.) According to Microsoft documentation this can be done using the OpenPrinter2 function (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/printdocs/openprinter2 ); I am afraid I don't have a working example yet.

Comment: Follow-up: adding PRINTER_OPTION_NO_CACHE option didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked `Enable bidirectional support` in the ports tab of the printer properties dialog? If it's grayed out, you will need to find a driver that supports bidirectional comms.

Comment: Actually, yes, I have checked that. I have abandoned that project because of the lack of results. Even the manufacturer (who provides an apparently working version of how to read back from the printer) cannot help because "they lost the source code". This is a feature we all love lo include in our app (automatically reporting printer serial number when on) but our business can handle that. Thanks, btw, for your help.